# Display stuck on 640x480

Tags: display-resolution

I have an old HP Proliant. I've got a dual-boot setup with Windows 7. Windows 7 tells me that I've got a Generic Non-PnP Monitor on Standard VGA Graphics adapter, and the display settings are set to 1024x768, which looks nice.

I've tried Xubuntu and Lubuntu, but I can't change my monitor settings: it's stuck on 640x480 and everything is too large to fit on the screen.

I've tried nomodeset in the Grub settings but that didn't help. I've seen several pieces of advice here, but they seem to deal with Nvidia adapters.
What can I do? I can't use this machine like this!

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00* 

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation E7220/E7221 Memory Controller Hub (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation E7220/E7221 PCI Express Root Port (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) PCI Express Port 1 (rev 03)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #1 (rev 03)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #2 (rev 03)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #3 (rev 03)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB UHCI #4 (rev 03)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev d3)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FR (ICH6/ICH6R) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 03)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801FR/FRW (ICH6R/ICH6RW) SATA Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) SMBus Controller (rev 03)
01:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6702PXH PCI Express-to-PCI Bridge A (rev 09)
01:00.1 PIC: Intel Corporation 6700/6702PXH I/OxAPIC Interrupt Controller A (rev 09)
02:01.0 Serial controller: MosChip Semiconductor Technology Ltd. PCI 9835 Multi-I/O Controller (rev 01)
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
0a:01.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82541GI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 05)
0a:03.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Rage XL PCI (rev 27)
```

It looks fine while installing... the splash and information screens are correct. It's only once it wants my login that the display is about 2 times too large for the screen.

Also... I seem to remember having this problem once before with this pc. Of course, I have no idea how I managed to fix it.

Comment: try issuing the command `xrandr` in a terminal and edit your question to include the output.  This will give some insight into your video outputs and available modes, and may allow someone to post a solution.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `lspci`.

Comment: Hmm, your xrandr output is not showing any video outputs. Usually you see VGA-0 or similar. This is deeper than my knowledge really goes but I suspect you are missing a driver.  What does "Additional Drivers" show?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to fix this:

1. Install Ubuntu 14.04 (I tried this using Lubuntu and Xubuntu). The screen display will be 640x480.
2. Ignore notifications of new Ubuntu versions.
3. In Software & Updates, under *Updates* tab set *Notify me of a new Ubuntu version* to *Never*.
4. In terminal, run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

   (`apt-get update` will install the necessary display driver)
5. Reboot. The display will now be correct.
6. In Software & Updates, under *Updates* tab change *Notify me of a new Ubuntu version* to *For long-term support versions*.
7. In terminal, run:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

   (This command took about 2 hours to complete execution.)

My old VGA monitor now works correctly with Ubuntu 16.04.